# Configure HG to use uncompressed transfer for specific servers

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgrc, kiln

Is it possible to configure Mercurial or TortoiseHG to always use uncompressed transfer when pulling or cloning from certain servers? We have repositories on Kiln that have sub-repositories located on the local LAN (mostly large binary files). When cloning or pulling from Kiln uncompressed should NOT be used, however the sub-repositories SHOULD use uncompressed. I would like to specify that any time HG hits up our local server, it should use uncompressed. We are using HgLab as our local repository server.

Answer (score 2):

HgLab author here. Mercurial does *not* support `--uncompressed` flags for pulls. It's only supported for initial clones.

As a sidenote: I'll be releasing HgLab 0.3.10 later this week, and pulls are *much* faster now (up to 20x increase).

*Update 8 months later*. HgLab now [has a way](http://hglabhq.com/blog/2014/3/25/hglab-1-4-released) to enforce streaming clones.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the local servers via SSH? If so, mercurial already disables compression (and you should also presumably disable compression in your ssh client). According to `hg help urls`:

> Mercurial doesn't use its own compression via SSH; the right thing to
>   do is to configure it in your ~/.ssh/config, e.g.:
>
> ```
> Host *.mylocalnetwork.example.com
>   Compression no   
> Host *
>   Compression yes
> ```

Comment: We are not using SSH. The local repositories are being served up by IIS7 using HgLab